# EDT and updating status textArea

Tags: java

I want to create new thread (for Server). I have textArea where I put my logs, I created a new class status which handles it. I run new thread for object "server", I try to "deliver" my status object to server and there do status.setStatus("blabal"); But there is a problem....

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Server.<init>(Server.java:16)
at Main.MainPanelButtonStartActionPerformed(Main.java:154)
at Main.access$000(Main.java:9)
at Main$1.actionPerformed(Main.java:63)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:308)
at 

javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at              java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Server.run(Server.java:23)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

My code:
   private void MainPanelButtonStartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
    if(!serverCreated) {           
        server = new Server(Integer.parseInt(MainPanelTextPort.getText())); 
        server.setStatusObj(status);
        serverThread = new Thread(server);          
        //SwingUtilities.invokeLater(serverThread); don't know how to use it correctly
        serverThread.start();              
        MainPanelButtonStart.setText("Stop");
        serverCreated = true;
    } else {
        if(!(serverThread.isInterrupted()))
        {
            try {
                server.getServerSocket().close();
            } catch(IOException e) {}

            serverThread.interrupt();
            MainPanelButtonStart.setText("Start");
            serverCreated = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The exception indicates a problem inside your `Server(int)` constructor. Show us that piece of code.

Comment: http://wklej.org/id/929231/

Answer (score 1):

The variable `status` is not instantiated on this line in the `Server` constructor:

```
status.setStatus("Server Created.");
```

Assuming this represents `RUNNING`, `STOPPED`, etc. these can be set internally in the `Server` class as it will be able to determine the run state of the server itself.

---

Regular `Threads` do not encapsulate correct interaction with the `Event Dispatch Thread`. [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) would be a better option here. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588543/server-based-swingworker-does-not-stop) has an example.

*Aside:* Given [Java code conventions](http://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html&ei=yEf5UImoE8ODhQej3YCwCA&usg=AFQjCNHCDpOmT2td7Qb91n4Zmrftnv-pDw&bvm=bv.41248874,d.ZG4), `MainPanelTextPort` would be represented as `mainPanelTextPort`.

Comment: Component MainPanelTextPort is initialized. How to use this SwingWorker with my code?

Comment: Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for the class `Server` and indicate line 16 where the error is occurring?

Comment: @user1916866, next time edit your question to show your code. External links such as yours just confuse people. You need to initialize the status variable with `status = new Status(...)` before you can access it's member functions. Java is not C++.

Comment: I did it before. In Main class constructor

Comment: @user1916866, you did not. You are calling `server.setStatusObj(status);` after the call to `Server` constructor.

Comment: Yes my misstake. What a fail. Thanks.

Comment: @user1916866 You _could_ pass that variable into the constructor but the `Server` itself should know the run status. See update.