# java socket thread working but no message

Tags: java, sockets

Hi I am trying create a small client server or server client chat message application as an experiment and to gain some knowledge and experience in java socket. I have been having problem sending and receiving messages. I do get a connection and the Thread looks like it is running but it wouldn't send or receive a message to each to other. I am not sure if the connection automatically closes once it connects but i know i am doing something wrong but i cant seem to find it. If you can help me that would be great. the code is below

---

Server:

```
public class ServerGUI extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
/*private JButton sendButton = new JButton("send");
private JButton connectButton = new JButton("Connect");
private JButton disconnectButton = new JButton("Disconnect");*/
private JTextField textMessage = new JTextField();
private JLabel connectMessageLabel = new JLabel("Waiting for Client");
private JTextArea messageTextArea = new JTextArea();
private JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel messageLabelPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel messageTextAreaPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel content = new JPanel();
private static String thisName= "<Me> ";
private static String friendLabel= "<My Friend> ";
private static JFrame serverFrame = new JFrame();
private int port= 0;
private String clientMessage=null;
private String myMessage=null;
private ServerSocket listenSocket;
private Socket connection;
private InputStream inStream;
private DataInputStream inDataStream;
private OutputStream outStream;
private DataOutputStream outDataStream;
private Thread runChatServer;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------serverGui------------------------------------------------------------
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public ServerGUI(int port){
    this.port = port;
    messageLabelPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 1, 1));
    messageLabelPanel.add(connectMessageLabel);
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 1, 1));
    //buttonPanel.add(connectButton);
    //buttonPanel.add(sendButton);
    buttonPanel.add(textMessage);
    textMessage.addKeyListener(this);
    textMessage.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    messageTextAreaPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(1, 1));
    messageTextAreaPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    messageTextAreaPanel.add(messageLabelPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    messageTextAreaPanel.add(new JScrollPane(messageTextArea),BorderLayout.CENTER);
    messageTextArea.setDisabledTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    messageTextArea.enable(false);
    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 1, 1));
    content.add(messageTextAreaPanel);
    content.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
    serverFrame.setContentPane(content);
    serverFrame.pack();
    serverFrame.setSize(450,550);
    serverFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    serverFrame.setVisible(true);
    serverFrame.setTitle("Chat Server");
    serverFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    startServer();
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------keyPressed------------------------------------------------------------
public void startServer(){
    System.out.println("startServer");
    try{
        listenSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Waiting for client");
        connection = listenSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Client Found");
        connectMessageLabel.setText("Client Found");
        runChatServer = new Thread(serverListeningAndChatting);
        runChatServer.start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex){

        System.out.println("No Connection Found");
        connectMessageLabel.setText("No Connection Found");
    }
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------listening------------------------------------------------------------
public void listening(){
    System.out.println("listening");
    try{
        inStream = connection.getInputStream();
        inDataStream = new DataInputStream(inStream);
        clientMessage = inDataStream.readUTF();
        if (clientMessage!= null){
            messageTextArea.append(clientMessage + "\n");
            clientMessage = null;
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex);}
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------sendMessage------------------------------------------------------------
public void sendMessage(){
    System.out.println("sendMessage");
    try{
        outStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        outDataStream = new DataOutputStream(outStream);

        if (myMessage!=null){
            outDataStream.writeUTF(myMessage);
            myMessage=null;
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){System.out.println("Message Failed");}
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------keyPressed------------------------------------------------------------
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        myMessage = friendLabel+ textMessage.getText();
        messageTextArea.append(thisName+textMessage.getText() +"\n");
        textMessage.setText("");
    }
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------main------------------------------------------------------------
public static void main (String args[]){
    new ServerGUI(8901);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------run------------------------------------------------------------
public Runnable serverListeningAndChatting = new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        while (true){
            System.out.println("Running");
            listening();
            sendMessage();
        }
    }
};

}
```

---

Client:

```
public class ClientGUI extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JTextField textMessage = new JTextField();
private JLabel connectMessageLabel = new JLabel("Connection failed or no Server is available");
private JTextArea messageTextArea = new JTextArea();
private JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel messageLabelPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel messageTextAreaPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel content = new JPanel();
private static String thisName= "<Me> ";
private static String friendLabel= "<My Friend> ";
private static JFrame clientFrame = new JFrame();
private int port =0;
private String remoteMachine =null;
private String clientMessage=null;
private String myMessage=null;
private Socket connection;
private InputStream inStream;
private DataInputStream inDataStream;
private OutputStream outStream;
private DataOutputStream outDataStream;
private Thread runChatClient;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------ClientGUI------------------------------------------------------------

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public ClientGUI(String remoteMachine, int port){
    this.port= port;
    this.remoteMachine = remoteMachine;
    messageLabelPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 1, 1));
    messageLabelPanel.add(connectMessageLabel);
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 1, 1));
    //buttonPanel.add(connectButton);
    //buttonPanel.add(sendButton);
    buttonPanel.add(textMessage);
    textMessage.addKeyListener(this);
    textMessage.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    messageTextAreaPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(1, 1));
    messageTextAreaPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    messageTextAreaPanel.add(messageLabelPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    messageTextAreaPanel.add(new JScrollPane(messageTextArea),BorderLayout.CENTER);
    messageTextArea.setDisabledTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    messageTextArea.enable(false);
    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 1, 1));
    content.add(messageTextAreaPanel);
    content.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
    clientFrame.setContentPane(content);
    clientFrame.pack();
    clientFrame.setSize(450,550);
    clientFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    clientFrame.setVisible(true);
    clientFrame.setTitle("Chat Client");
    clientFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    startClient();

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------startClient------------------------------------------------------------
public void startClient(){
    System.out.println("startClient");
    try{
        System.out.println("Connecting to Server");
        connection = new Socket(remoteMachine, port);
        System.out.println("Server Found");
        connectMessageLabel.setText("Server Found");
        runChatClient = new Thread(clientListeningAndChatting);
        runChatClient.start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println("No Connection Found");
        connectMessageLabel.setText("No Connection Found");
    }

}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------keyPressed------------------------------------------------------------
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        myMessage = friendLabel+ textMessage.getText();
        messageTextArea.append(thisName+textMessage.getText() +"\n");
        textMessage.setText("");
    }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------listening------------------------------------------------------------
public void listening(){
    System.out.println("listening");
    try{
        inStream = connection.getInputStream();
        inDataStream = new DataInputStream(inStream);
        clientMessage = inDataStream.readUTF();
        if (clientMessage!= null){
            messageTextArea.append(clientMessage + "\n");
            clientMessage = null;
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){System.out.println("Disconnected");}
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------sendMessage------------------------------------------------------------
public void sendMessage(){
    System.out.println("sendMessage");
    try{
        outStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        outDataStream = new DataOutputStream(outStream);
        if (myMessage!=null){
            outDataStream.writeUTF(myMessage);
            myMessage=null;
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){System.out.println("Message Failed");}
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------main------------------------------------------------------------
public static void main (String args[]){
    new ClientGUI(null, 8901);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------run------------------------------------------------------------
public Runnable clientListeningAndChatting = new Runnable(){

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running");
        while (true){
            listening();
            sendMessage();
        }
    }
};
}
```

Comment: Can you show us just the communications code i.e. socket code which is having a problem.  ideally this should be in a class which doesn't have *any GUI code* in it.

Comment: yeah sure here it is This is the listening code------------>>>>>

public void listening(){
  System.out.println("listening");
  try{
   inStream = connection.getInputStream();
   inDataStream = new DataInputStream(inStream);
   clientMessage = inDataStream.readUTF();
   if (clientMessage!= null){
    messageTextArea.append(clientMessage + "\n");
    clientMessage = null;
   }
  }catch(Exception ex){System.out.println("Disconnected");}
 }

Comment: and this is the sending code ----------------> 

public void sendMessage(){
  System.out.println("sendMessage");
  try{
   outStream = connection.getOutputStream();
   outDataStream = new DataOutputStream(outStream);
   System.out.println(myMessage);
   if (myMessage!=null){
    outDataStream.writeUTF(myMessage);
    myMessage=null;
   }
  }catch(Exception ex){System.out.println("Message Failed");}
 }

Comment: because it is an experiment i have left them all in one class

Comment: Please don't post more than one line of code in a comment. It is completely illegible. Edit it into your answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Socket using in a swing applet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244400/socket-using-in-a-swing-applet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement

```
listenSocket.accept();
```

is a blocking call is is blocking the `EDT`. This and any other network access calls should be handled by a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). As Swing is single threaded, no events can be processed so no messages can be exchanged between the client & server.

Use `SwingWorker` over `Thread`—it takes care of GUI interaction tasks.

Comment: if that blocks it. How do i get a establish the connection between them and send messages to them?

Comment: sorry i didnt see that message swingerWork? never used that before

Comment: u no what i dont no how to use it. i'll try look that up

Comment: Here is a [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588543/server-based-swingworker-does-not-stop)

Comment: dude your a legend! i hope i get it working :D if not it is a good lesson never knew about SwingerWorker